# How to copy vs code settings from one github account to another

Tags: visual-studio-code, synchronization

I have two github accounts and currently vs code settings is synced with one account but I want copy the settings to the second github account and sync from there. How to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option I found was to log out of settings sync (while preserving data locally), log into the preferred Github account and import the settings from local state:

1. Sign out of settings sync: open the command palette with <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and select "Settings sync: turn off" – **DO NOT select the checkbox to clear your data from the cloud!**
2. Turn on settings sync and sign into your new Github account: open the command palette and select "Settings sync: turn on"
3. Specify how to [merge your settings data](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync#_merge-or-replace):

> **Merge**: Selecting this option will merge local settings with remote settings from the cloud.
>
> **Replace Local**: Selecting this option will overwrite local settings with remote settings from the cloud.
>
> **Merge Manually**: Selecting this option will open Merges view where you can merge preferences one by one.